# .on() not working with HTML added after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

[EDIT]

[Here's a jsFiddle with the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/jAs5X/)

[/EDIT]

I'm working on a site with a datepicker ([jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker)).

Next to the `datepicker` there is going to be a `time dropdown` that needs to change if the user selects a weekday or weekend from the `datepicker`.

I've written this code to try and grab the `ui-datepicker-week-end` class from the datepicker to test if it's a weekend or not, but I can't get anything to `console.log` at all.

```
$('.ui-datepicker').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

[Here's the dev site](http://alantyler.codeplayground.co.uk/contact/) as it stands. I think the issue is that the HTML for the `datepicker` is added in with jQuery and so `.on()` doesn't know it's there to pick up the class? I know `.live()` would do it, but that's depreciated now I believe.

Any ideas how to grab the class fom the clicked `td`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntaxe is good, but you probably aren't binding the event after initializing datepicker, but before.

Make sure you are doing `$('.yourClass').datepicker()` before `$('.ui-datepicker').on...`.

Doing `console.log($('.ui-datepicker').length)` before the `.on()` will tell you if the datepicker is initialized.

In the case it isnt working, it mean (but i don't think so) that `.ui-datepicker` is dynamic aswell. You'll have to target a parent :

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.ui-datepicker tr', function(){});
```

---

## Edit

jQuery UI seem to stop propagation, hence can't bind a click event.

But it have an option allowing to bind an event when you select a date:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Pass it in the option object when initialiszing datepicker.

It is better to use this since you can also select dates with keyboard (so no click triggered).

http://jsfiddle.net/jAs5X/2/

Comment: Hey, the `console.log($('.ui-datepicker').length)` returns `1`, so that's good news? But still no luck with my code

Comment: Hmm, I've added a jsFiddle to the question if this might help?

Comment: Hey, great! It logs, which is great. But the reason I was doing this was to check if they selected a weekend or weekday. The log there just logs my input field :(

Comment: @lukeseager see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jAs5X/3/. jQuery UI pass a date object in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Swap the syntax around. `on()` should be bound to the nearest static parent of the dynamic content:

```
$('tr').on('click', '.ui-datepicker', function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work still. I'm wondering if the click is on the `a` rather than the `td` now?

Comment: I'd have expected it to propagate. Anyway, the above will bind to the `.ui-datepicker` element. Whenever it's click, you should get a console message.

Comment: @BenM the `tr` is a child of `.ui-datepicker`.

Comment: Hmm, just tried changing the console.log to a string just saying 'click', still doesn't seem to want to do anything :S

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker td', function() {
    console.log(this.className);
});
```

Where `#date` is the static element (*the datepicker*) which was available in the document on page load and bind the click event on the td of `.ui-datepicker` then you can get the class name of the clicked td in the calendar.

Comment: There is no static element available on page load for the datepicker I'm afraid. It's just added to the end of the wrapper dynamically, not wrapped in any div I've made.

Comment: then you can delegate to the document itself.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to want to do anything. Tried `$(document)` and tried a bunch of different selectors. Not sure what's up with it.

Answer (score -1):

Change to

```
$('.ui-datepicker tr').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```